# ESXi requires a 4k monitor for a Mac server, how can I display this on a server room 1080p monitor?

Tags: vmware-esxi, mac, keyboard-video-mouse

Apple macOS is licensed for virtualization only if running on Apple hardware. VMWare ESXi 7.0 Update 3 has support for [Apple's 2018 Intel (Macmini8,1)](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=server&productid=50694&vcl=true). This works well. However, I need to roll around a cart with a 4k monitor because VMWare ESXi apparently will only output 4k 2160p ([the native resolution](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP782)) to the monitor.

We presently have several of these Macs on an HDMI KVM with Keyboard (USB) support. I've purchased many items ([This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VP37KMB), [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09NCKD8B3), and [that](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08WKM473M)) to attempt to downscale to 1080p.

VMWare displays at 1080p during boot (the loading screens), but switches to 4k once the management screen is displayed (showing version, IP, and allowing a login).

Is there some way to force ESXi to only display 1080p? Or a downscaler that works from the Mac's HDMI output to a 1080p monitor?

Comment: Can you not just swap out the 1080p monitor for a 4K one?

Comment: Tested with a borrowed 32" monitor, it works. But the monitor was too large to fit into a 19" rack. I've had trouble googling/amazoning for a 17" 4k monitor or I'd have done that.

Comment: Hi James - I don't know where you are in the world but if you google "Dragon Touch S1 4K monitor" that might well be what you're looking for, alternatively LG's "22MD4KA" might be small enough.

Comment: That works, ASIN B08RN6W9CZ. > "VESA mount holes on the back"